# Schema Hiding while creating the component

Tags: schema

I would like to hide some selected schemas so that when creating a component, they don't show up in the schema dropdown. How can I do this?

Answer (score 10):

To hide schema from specific users or groups, place them in a folder and apply security which reduces the *read* permissions to specific groups. When the drop down is generated in the create component view, only schema to which the user has *read* permissions will be displayed.

I typically have a few folders for schema (e.g. System Schema, Content Schema and Advanced Schema). Authors get *read* permissions on the Content Schema folder but not the others. The other folders have *read* permissions for Chief Editors or Power Users.

Comment: +1--the same authorization approach applies to Component Template and Page Template drop-down selections.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Chris' answer, you could also set the `Linked Schema` on the Folder, and set this as `Mandatory`.

[image]

This will force all Components created in that Folder to use that Schema, and will not display the Schema dropdown at all.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Many times this kind of question arises whenever we create a new blueprint for multi brand websites, ofcourse we have to manage different schemas for different brands in a single structure blueprint . Here our question is how to manage different schemas for different brands in a single structure blueprint structure, yes we have to create all the schemas under schema publication and we have to divide schemas based on the brands into different folders and give permission for each folder based on brands so that whenever a single brand users login they will never able to see the other schema of other brands so you have to provide permission to folder level.

There is one another way to divide your schemas based on your brand by providing the prefix name so that you will easily recognised your schema whenever you are creating a component or or or assigning schemas as linked schema in CTs, but in this scenario every brand publication will be able to display all schemas for all the brands.

But the best one is firstone